# Find the line integral of $F=\langle 1,y \rangle$ around the ellipse

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the line integral of $F=\langle1,y\rangle$ around the ellipse $x^2/9 + y^2/36= 1$ where $x,y\ge 0$ oriented clockwise.

if not clear :- [Please see image for description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sczQl.jpg)

My solution is not being accepted , Please help.

$F=\langle 1,y\rangle$, 
Ellipse  = $x^2/9+y^2/36 = 1$
Parametrizing 
$x = 3\cos(t) , y=6\sin(t) , 
r(t)=\langle3\cos(t),6\sin(t)\rangle ,
 r'(t)=\langle-3\sin(t),6\cos(t)\rangle$

Function $F$ is $F=\langle 1,6\sin(t)\rangle$, take the dot product
$\langle 1,6\sin(t)\rangle·\langle-3\sin(t),6\cos(t)\rangle\to -3\sin(t)+36\sin(t)\cos(t)$

Integrating :-
$\int_{0}^{2\pi} -3\sin(t)+36\sin(t)\cos(t) dt$

Let $u = \sin(t);\,du = \cos(t)dt$
$;u^2/2$ 
$[3\cos(t)+ 36\sin^2(t)/2]$ from $0$ to $2\pi$

### $3\cos(2\pi)=3$ , sin value goes to 0

$3cos(0) = 3\;;3 - 3 = 0$

This is incorrect, the answer is something else, your help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Read the question carefully. It says "$x,y\ge 0$, oriented clockwise."

Comment: Sir, I realized what you said. I changed my orientation in the r'(t) from <-3sin(t),6cos(t)> to <3sin(t), -6cos(t)> , for counter clockwise , we are told not to change signs as that is always positive. But I am still getting zero, I should be getting a negative value, this is what the material says. I am thankful for your help.

Comment: You're still not paying attention. It says $x,y\ge 0$, so what $t$-values is this?

Comment: Sir, Around the ellipse which means it is going all the way from 0 -> 2pi. Both x and y are greater than or equal to 0. Is my parametrization incorrect? Oriented clockwise means, first quadrant both x and y are positive I mean both sin and cos ? Thank you for your help. Sir, I tried pi/2 , the result is 18. Since its going clockwise, i should take its negative. Is this right ? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Mr.Ted Shifrin Thank you. I finally got the answer, I apologize it is not 18.

Here is the answer, like you said it goes from 0 - pi/2 , where both x and y values will be >0.

Take the negative of the integral as it is oriented clockwise.

$-[3cos(t)+36sin^2(t)/2]$

$-[3cos⁡(t)+36sin^2⁡(t)/2]$   from  $0$ to $π/2$

$-[0+18 - (3 + 0)] = -[18-3] =  -15 $

This answer was accepted. 
But if you can , please add some general rules to follow for these questions so that it may help others.